# Duplicate rows in CSV should add up using python dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

i have CSV file that contains duplicate records that needs to be add up for measure columns.

Example:
Source file

```
Ctry Week Sales$ Units
IN    01    10     02
IN    01    10     02
US    02    21     04
US    02    21     04
CN    01    18     03
UK    02    09     01
```

Expected result

```
Ctry Week Sales$ Units
IN    01    20     04
US    02    42     08
CN    01    18     03
UK    02    09     01
```

Comment: Please provide a more readable example. You can use this to format a table: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ then select format as code (the icon with {}) . Do you mean you want to group by a certain column and sum?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv'); df.groupby(['Ctry','Week']).sum()`.

Comment: Hi Hoang, Thanks for quick reply. Code has run without error but no change in the file still the record shows as source file only